# How to use Django logging with gunicorn

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn, supervisord

I have a Django 1.6 site running with gunicorn, managed by supervisor. During tests and runserver I have logging on the console, but with gunicorn the statements don't show up anywhere (not even ERROR level logs). They should be in /var/log/supervisor/foo-stderr---supervisor-51QcIl.log but they're not. I have celery running on a different machine using supervisor and its debug statements show up fine in its supervisor error file.

Edit:
Running gunicorn in the foreground shows that none of my error messages are being logged to stderr like they are when running manage.py. This is definitely a gunicorn problem and not a supervisor problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a response on GitHub:

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/708

> Since you have passed disable_existing_loggers the Gunicorn loggers are disabled when Django loads your logging configuration. If you are setting this because you want to disable some default Django logging configuration, make sure you add back the gunicorn loggers, gunicorn.error and gunicorn.access with whatever handlers you want.

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/your-app.conf`you should set log paths:

```
stdout_logfile=/var/log/your-app.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/your-app.log
```

Comment: I already have a stderr file, but the logging statements aren't showing up.

Answer (score 2):

First, in your supervisor config for the gunicorn script, be sure to define

```
stdout_logfile=/path/to/logfile.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

That will make stdout and stderr go to the same file.
Now, on your gunicorn script, be sure to call the process with the following argument

```
gunicorn YourWSGIModule:app --log-level=critical
```