# Gunicorn blocking logging for django app using docker-compose

Tags: django, docker-compose, gunicorn

my django app has a pretty simple logging set up

```
DEBUG = True
LOGGING_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs')
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOGGING_DIR, 'django2.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'SysLog': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
                'address': ('logsXX.papertrailapp.com', XXXXX)
            },

    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'SysLog'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',

        },
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'SysLog'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',

        },
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'SysLog'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

When I run `python3 manage.py runserver --settings=my_app.local` I can see the logging work in console, in my file and is pushed to papertrail.

However, when I use `docker-compose` to run the app I'm only seeing output to console for explicitly logged errors like `logger.info('some_error')` but not for requests, nothing is writing to the file I have and nothing is being sent to papertrail.

My docker compose file looks like this:

```
# docker-compose.test.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: local-build:latest
    command: ["gunicorn", "my_app.wsgi", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", '-t', '500']
    env_file: [env.txt]
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: my_app.local
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
```

I've seen this post where someone seemed to have a similar issue:[How to use Django logging with gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340049/how-to-use-django-logging-with-gunicorn) but `disable_existing_loggers` is already set to `False`.

Answer (score -9):

I found the answer, I had to change a logger to `gunicorn` and it works perfectly now.

Comment: What do you mean? More details please.